# <html> margin unwanted spacing, ALL sizes

Tags: css

no way I could fix this issue HTML tag has some margin-right. what's the fix?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

[image: ]]

Comment: if you identified that it is a margin-right then why you didn't try to set margin-right to 0?

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` isn't actually on `<html>`, but rather on `<body>`, where most browsers adds `8px` of `margin` by default:

```html
Text
```

You can remove this by setting:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
Text
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it

```
html, body {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-right: 0;
}
```